# How do I create 4 of the same excel table (i.e different views) that update simultaneously

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with LOTS of columns, however, to separate these columns into smaller tables would increase the manual processes.

What I would like to achieve is to have a table that is linked to 3 other views of the same data.

I created this on Coda however with the sort of numbers we are using it was too laggy and the company is already familiar with excel.

But to show the functionality, here is a link to view;
https://coda.io/d/LAP-Sheets_dGgLPS7V1d8/_sudZF

Basically, I have the first table, which shows every column.
Then, there are 'on market', 'referencing' and 'rent collection', which are all linked views of the first table, just with a lot of hidden columns so it is more manageable.

When you update one of the tables, it updates on the other 3, and if you press the button to change the status, it moves it to the next table.

This is perfect - except moving it across to excel is proving very difficult.

I have built out the first table - but I don't know how to achieve the different views of it.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It looks like you are using Excel as a database, and Excel **is not** a database enviroment. Yes, millions of people do it, but because you can do easy *lists*. I would say you need a different approach for this, like using ms-Access or SQL or something like it. That way, you can update the way you want.

Comment: We are currently building an SQL database as we are developing a new website, however, we need a temporary fix as all our business processes are currently working from excel and it's too messy

Comment: This will not be simple but you could use the `Worksheet_Change` event to propagate changes between sheets provided each sheet has a usable "key" in each row which allows unique records to be identified.  Try that out and post back with code if you run into problems.